# Differences between Interop DCP and SMPTE DCP

Tags: smpte, dcp, cinema

Hi,

right now I'm writing on my thesis and I try to find out the main differences between the Interop- and SMPTE-DCP specifications regarding the amount of audio-channels that are available. 
The problem I ran into is that the SMPTE specs are only sold via the SPMTE store and I don't even know which *.pdf I should buy to get the desired informations.

So far, I've only found out, that an Interop-DCP allows 16 channels of audio for each channel-configuration (5.1 / 7.1SDDS / 7.1DS) in up to 24Bit and 96kHz.

So my question right now are:

-Does anybody of you know, if a SMPTE-DCI allows more than these 16 channels?

-And are there more channel-configurations than 5.1, 7.1SDDS and 7.1DS available?

-And can you think about a way to implement more than 16 channels into a DCP?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really writing a thesis on filmsound that describes the differences between the different DCP standards, then Insuggest you start by reading the info on the DCI site.

Comment: Hey ErikG,
my thesis is about "3D Audio"-systems, so the DCP specifications are ofc part of it. I read the info given at dcimovies.com, but I couldn't find any informations about the difference between Interop- and SMPTE-DCP there.

Comment: I'm no expert on dcp for sure. But what is that you want to know?
The technical differences, or how and why the standard format changed from one to the other?


Comment: http://isdcf.com/papers/ISDCF-Doc2-DCP-TransitionReview.pdf

Answer (score 1):

SMPTE DCP2000 = 24 audio channels

Comment: Hey sven,
thanks for your answer. Do you have some kind of source for that (since I need some kind of 'official statement' for my thesis)?


Answer (score 1):

support for new immersive sound formats like Auro3D (11.1 -15.1) and Atmos 7.1 and 9.1 ('Objects' will be stored in an additional auxillary part of the DCP).